# React Native: Modal screen is not closing with a tap

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-modal

In my RN 0.62.2 app/Android emulator, I am looking for a way to close modal showing an image by just tapping the screen instead of putting up a close button. Here is what the app shall be doing:

```
1. an image is displayed on screen
2. clicking the image pops up a modal screen which fill the width of the whole screen.
3. user can zoom in and out of the image on modal screen  
4. as soon as a user taps the modal screen, then the modal screen is closed.
```

Here is the render code:

```
      import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';
      import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
      import ReactNativeZoomableView from '@dudigital/react-native-zoomable-view/src/ReactNativeZoomableView';
      const [modalDialog, setModalDialog] = useState(null);

      return (
            <React.Fragment>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>setModalDialog(index)}>  //Touch triggers popping up of modal below
                <FastImage   //<<<===equivalent of Image. The image shown in square box
                    source={{uri:img_source}} 
                    resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover} 
                    style={{
                        width:width, 
                        height:ht, 
                        verticalAlign:0,
                        paddingTop:0,
                    }}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> setModalDiaglog(null)}>  //<<<===press shall close modal. But it is NOT
                <Modal isVisible={modalDialog===index}>
                    
                        <ReactNativeZoomableView  //<<<===zoom in and out of image
                            maxZoom={3}
                            minZoom={0.5}
                            zoomStep={0.5}
                            initialZoom={1}
                            bindToBorders={true}
                            captureEvent={true}
                        >
                            <FastImage //<<==show image with full width of the device screen
                                source={{uri:img_source}} 
                                resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover} 
                                style={{
                                    width:modalWidth, 
                                    height:modalHt, 
                                    verticalAlign:0,
                                    paddingTop:0,
                                }}
                            />
                        </ReactNativeZoomableView>
                    
                </Modal>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </React.Fragment>
            );
```

The code above works through `1-3` but not `4`. The issue is that the modal screen can't be closed on Android emulator (mimicing a tap with a left mouse click). Tried to put `<TouchableOpacity>` inside of `<Modal>` and it didn't work. The `<TouchableOpacity>` next to `<Modal>`just didn't respond to press. How the app can close `Modal` with a tap?

Comment: Have you try put `<TouchableOpacity>` between `<ReactNativeZoomableView>` and `<Modal>` with `flex:1` ?

Comment: Yes, I did and didn't work. Add flex:1 to TouchableOpacity and there is no difference.

Comment: `import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';` Are you import from react-native? Don't import from `react-native-gesture-handler`

Comment: It worked after adding flex:1 to TouchableOpacity style. What is the explanation? Many thanks. Yes, it was imported from RN.

Comment: I guess it doesn't spread out without setting height, `flex:1` let it spread out to the container so that have it's height and then could touch?

Comment: The height may be minimal without flex:1. Will vote if you post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height may be minimal without `flex:1`.

So you could add `flex:1` to `<TouchableOpacity>` style, give it a height, then you could tap it to work.